# R - Removing weekends from dataframe in R

Tags: r, weekday, weekend

My data looks like this for one column:

```
Date    AED.USD
03/01/2005  3.6726
04/01/2005  3.6726
05/01/2005  3.6725
06/01/2005  3.6726
07/01/2005  3.6725
08/01/2005  NA
09/01/2005  NA
10/01/2005  3.6726
11/01/2005  3.6725
12/01/2005  3.6726
13/01/2005  3.6725
14/01/2005  3.6726
15/01/2005  NA
16/01/2005  NA
17/01/2005  3.6725
18/01/2005  3.6726
19/01/2005  3.6725
20/01/2005  3.6725
21/01/2005  3.6725
```

I want to remove the dates with the weekends, I have tried using

```
x <- seq(as.Date("2005-01-03"),as.Date("2016-11-30"),by = 1)
x <- fxdl_weekdays[!weekdays(x) %in% c('Saturday','Sunday')]
```

this shows the dates in the values section but how am I supposed to show this in an updated data frame.

Comment: You're missing a comma.  Your code is currently subsetting columns, not rows.  But I would just do `df[!chron::is.weekend(as.Date(df$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")), ]` where `df` is your data

Answer (score 2):

```
df[which(weekdays(as.Date(df$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
          %in% c('Monday','Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday')), ]
```